# Problem waking Ubuntu 20.04.3 from sleep

Tags: suspend, dell, inspiron, wakeup

I have a Dell Inspiron 5415 with dual boot Windows 10 + Ubuntu 20.04.3. The processor is Ryzen 5 5500U. I can't wake my laptop after putting it into sleep. It works fine on Windows though. While sleeping, I can change the backlight key brightness and also, if I press some random combination of keys, it wakes up from sleep. Anyone has a solution for this?